# How can I upload many PDF files into a Oracle database, with multiple file browser fields in APEX?

Tags: database, forms, upload, oracle-apex

I need to build a page for my APEX app where the end users will upload about 12 pdf files. A file browser field for each document is necessary to ensure the user uploads all documents.

Creating the file browser fields is the easy part. When I submit the form with test files only one entry is created in the database. I would like to create an entry for each document.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [plugin](https://apex.world/ords/f?p=100:710:14017667022354::::P710_PLG_ID:DE.DANIELH.DROPZONE) with an ease to manage uploads.

[image]

In the attributes, specify the collection name

[image]

and then use a pl/sql  procedure or process as:

`declare CURSOR l_cur_files IS SELECT blob001 AS file_content,c001 as filename, c002 as mimetype FROM apex_collections WHERE collection_name = 'DROPZONE_UPLOAD';`

`begin  FOR l_rec_files IN l_cur_files LOOP insert into yourtable(fileblob,name etc) values (l_rec_files.file_content, l_rec_files.filename) END LOOP;  end;`

Comment: Thank you, but I need the user to upload file by file on the page. This is required to make sure he sends all the required documents. I tried duplicating the filebrowser item and duplicating the form region. On both cases only null lines are added to the DB

Comment: Then just add 12 item of type this plugin?